# Haskell and calling function.

Tags: haskell

```
data S = Sa Int
type PMO = StateT Int (ErrorT String IO)

cs :: S -> PMO ()
cs _ = do
  mem <- get -- (*)
  return ()
```

I've highlighted the line with (*). I have doubts why `get` function can be called. I know that `get` is function from `State` monad but I cannot see/grasp how it is known that there is such monad in fact. I see that returned type is PMO but it is just returned value. What does it has in common with `get`?

Mainly, I have an experience with imperative language programming so it makes me trouble to understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this State monad code works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506839/how-does-this-state-monad-code-works)

Comment: (`get` works much like `fresh` in that example, except that the underlying function of `get` is simply `\s -> (s, s)`, while `fresh` also modifies the state.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the type of `get`:

```
get :: MonadState s m => m s
```

And since in the type signature of `cs` you've told the compiler what `m` is, `get` becomes:

```
get :: StateT Int (ErrorT String IO) Int
```

That's just a monadic value, not a function. So where does the value named `mem` come from? Ultimately, the value that `get` provides comes from the initial state value supplied by `runStateT` (or `execStateT` or `evalStateT`).

If that still seems mysterious, I recommend studying up on how the state monad works.

Comment: "And since in the type signature of cs you've told the compiler what m is, get becomes:" I cannot understand it. Can you say more about it?

Comment: In the type of `get` there are two type variables. `s` is the type of the state value and can be anything, in general. `m` must be some data type which has a `MonadState` instance. Without type annotations, the compiler will use the most general types it can. Your `cs` function would end up with a type like `cs :: MonadState a m => b -> m ()` since there are only two things the compiler knows for sure: your `m` has a `MonadState` instance (because you use `get`), and you return the value `()`.

Comment: Now since you explicitly gave it a type signature (which is good practice on top-level definitions), you are putting additional constraints on the type checker. In fact, you've told it exactly which instance of `MonadState` you want: `StateT Int (ErrorT String IO)`.  Thus `get` goes from `MonadState s m => m s` to `StateT Int (ErrorT String IO) Int`. (i.e. `m = StateT Int (ErrorT String IO)` and `s = Int`)

Comment: it is an awesome explanation! :)  Please explain me from where a state value is taken? I suppose that there is a initial state passed with `runStateT` but I cannot see how it is passed. Please note: I just called `get` function and I have a state. But, how did I get it? Magic? How the passing of state is "chaining". I would like to understand it.

Comment: I'm sure a search for "how does state monad work" would come up with a lot of results. A quick non-rigorous explanation is that the state monad is a function `\s -> (a,s)` where bind (`>>=`) 'composes' states. Thus, it's a function which you 'run' by applying to a `s` value. This is what `runState` and the like do.