# Curious about why get in StateT monad transformer returns a instead of (a, s)

Tags: haskell

I was reading the [StateT monad transformer's source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.html#get), as it reads like this:

```
get :: (Monad m) => StateT s m s
get = state $ \ s -> (s, s)
```

I expanded the above code by switching out `state` and got this, but still fail to see why it's not returning a tuple.

```
a <- StateT (return . (\ s -> (s, s)))
```

From the code above it seemed `get` returns a tuple `(s, s)`, which looked fine, but I'm wondering why when using it, `get` returned an `Int`, instead of `(Int, Int)`?

I traced a lot of source code trying to find when or what changed it but to no avail.

```
w :: StateT Int IO String
w = do
  a <- get
  liftIO $ print a -- 2, but why? shouldn't this be (2, 2) instead?
  return $ show a

result = runStateT w 2 -- ("2",2)
```

Comment: `get` returns a value of type `(StateT Int IO) String` (I've put the parentheses in to be more explicit, they are implied anyway), so using the `<-` notation to "extract  the underlying value", `a` is simply a `String`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, `(StateT Int IO) String` was my understanding of how a monad transformer is constructed, I'm just hoping to see the real code that made it happen and as I said I failed to see that from the source code?

Comment: Ah OK, in that case you need to be more explicit about what you want explained. I was simply answering the question in the comment, as to why `liftIO $ print a` was not showing a tuple.

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m curious about because judeging by the source listed above it looks like this? get = state $ \ s -> (s, s) which is returning a tuple? @RobinZigmond

Comment: Do you understand how `do` notation is "desugared"? This `do` block translates into `w = get >>= \a -> liftIO (print a) >> return (show a)` - the `a` here is of type `String`, even though `get` is of type `StateT Int IO String`. (`>>=` has type signature `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m  b`, `m` in this case is `StateT Int IO`).

Comment: @DonKlein No, `get` doesn't return anything. It *is* a value that wraps a *function* that returns a tuple. Its monad instance defines `>>=` to pass part of that return value, once it actually gets called via `runState(T)`, as the argument to the next function.

Comment: @chepner that makes sense, but can you show me where this monad instance is defined? I want to see how it’s >>= actually return part of the value (for that I had flipped through endless source code today trying to find just that), thanks!

Comment: [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.html#line-221). this is the source for the `Monad` instance [from here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT). You find it under "Instances", the second entry.

Comment: Note that `m >>= f` doesn't actually return the value. It creates a *new* `StateT` value whose wrapped function unwraps `m` and "composes* its function with `f`. `a <- get` is desugared as `get >>= \a -> ...`, where the `...` continuation is everything that follows in the `do` block.

Comment: see the `k a` in the last line of `>>=` implementation there, `runStateT (k a) s'`? that's what it means that only the part of the tuple - i.e. its `fst` field - is passed along as the "returned value" from a previous computation step into the next computation step, while the `s'` in `( a  , s')` is tagging along as part of the stateful computation "pipeline". So we "compute" the `a` "value", and `s` "state" is maintained on the side for us.

Comment: @WillNess Ah that clicked for me, actually I stared at that instance implementation for like an hour today but didn't realize the key lies in the (k a) part, thanks for point that out, all's good now!

Comment: see [e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31506839/849891) for some illuminating (hopefully) re-writes in the answers. (disclaimer: one of them is by me). it's for simple State (no transformers) so should be simpler to follow. transformers just juggle the additional monads around, but the essence of state passing is the same.

Comment: Don't put an answer in the question itself. You can post an answer to your own question if you fee the need.

Answer (score 3):

A value of type `StateT s m a`, modulo `newtype` wrappers, is a function with type `s -> m (a, s)`.

The function `(return . (\ s -> (s, s)))` has type `s -> m (s, s)`, hence once it is wrapped by the `StateT` constructor becomes a value of type `StateT s m s`.

Note that a value of type `StateT s m (s, s)` would instead involve a function of type `s -> m (s, (s, s))` which is not what we are using here.

Your confusion seem to arise from the "other" `s` in `m (s, s)`, which does not contribute to `x` when we run `x <- get`. To understand why, it's useful to think to think to what a stateful computation performs:

- First, we read the old state of type `s`. This is the `s -> ..` part in the type `s -> m (a, s)`.
- Then, we run some action in the monad `m`. This is the `.. -> m ..` part in the type `s -> m (a, s)`.

  - The monadic action returns a new state, to replace the old one. This is the `.. -> .. (.., s)` part in the type `s -> m (a, s)`.
  - Finally, monadic action also returns a value, of a possibly different type `a`. This the `.. -> .. (a, ..)` part in the type `s -> m (a, s)`.

Running `x <- action` handles all these types automatically for us, and lets `x` to have the result type `a`, only.

Concretely, consider this imperative pseudo-code:

```
global n: int

def foo():
   if n > 5:
      print ">5"
      n = 8
      return "hello"
   else:
      print "not >5"
      n = 10
      return "greetings"
```

In an imperative language, we would type this as `foo(): string`, since it returns a string, disregarding its side effects to the global `n: int` and the printed messages.

In Haskell, we would instead model that using a more precise type like

```
Int -> IO (String, Int)
^-- the old n
       ^-- the printed stuff
           ^-- the returned string
                   ^-- the new n
```

Again, running `x <- foo()` we want `x: string`, not `x: (string, int)`, following what would happen in an imperative language.

If instead we had a function

```
global n: int

def bar():
   old_n = n
   n = n + 5
   return old_n
```

we would use the type

```
Int -> IO (Int, Int)
```

since the returned value is an `Int` now. Similarly,

```
global n: int

def get():
   return n
```

could use the same type

```
Int -> IO (Int, Int)
```

Now, one might argue that the second `Int` is not strictly necessary here, since `get()` is not really producing a new state -- it's not *changing* the value of `n`. Still, it's convenient to use a type of the same form, `s -> m (a, s)`, as any function which *could* change the state. This is so that it can be used together with any other function having a similar type.